# how to track pinterest pin events

Tags: pinterest

I am working on a site which is similar to this page- http://fab.com/feed/
Here, i need to track when a user clicks the pin button.I found that Pinterest havnt got any API's til now and while searching i got some codes which will track the clicks on pin button on my site.But this will not be an exact solution as user can click the button and then close the iframe which pops out without actually pinning the content.So can any one here helps me out?

Comment: You should give more examples, like the programming language you use for your website, what have you tried untill now (the codes you say you tried), etc.

Answer (score 2):

The only solution we figured out was listening to the click event on pinit button and assuming user added it to pinterest if they clicked on the button. Pinterest is not quite ready with a callback mechanism for pin. They do have a roadmap to build this feature.

sources: I developed fab.com/feed ;)

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem a while ago and found a way to do it rather nicely. However, because the solution is not as straightforward as it should be, I wrote an article about it, which you can find [here](http://codeaid.net/php/tracking-facebook-twitter-and-pinterest-interactions).

Hope that helps!